# `exec -a` does not work for scripts: is there a ways to easily change $0 in scripts?

Tags: python, bash, arguments, command-line-arguments

If I want to automatically "wrap" a program (in order to add some environment variables to it), one solution is to rename the program in something like `myscript-wrapped`, and create a new file `myscript` with the following content:

```sh
#/usr/bin/env bash
export PATH=/my/new/path
exec -a "$0" "myscript-wrapped" "$@"
```

The `-a "$0"` being used to ensure that the first argument of `myscript-wrapped` is `myscript` instead of`myscript-wrapped`, and the `"$@"` is used to forward the arguments.

If `myscript-wrapped` is a binary file, then everything works perfectly, i.e. it thinks that the first argument is `myscript`. But if `myscript-wrapped` is a script (bash, python, ...) like:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "my name is $0"
```

then this fails miserably: I get the output `my name is myscript-wrapped` instead of `my name is myscript`. I guess this happens because of the level of indirection: `myscript` calls `bash`, and then `bash` calls `myscript-wrapped`.

What is the best way to avoid that issue? If the script language is nice enough, one solution would be to edit the script `myscript-wrapped` and add a line at the very beginning like `BASH_ARGV0="myscript"`, but this require a quite recent bash version (5 at least, I'm still running version 4 on my system). The second problem of that solution is that it is very language-specific, and we need to write a different solution for any language. Any better idea? I am also happy to replace `myscript` with some compiled C if it is required.

My use case is that I'd like to improve Nix wrappers (Nix package manager uses heavily wrappers to ensure purity/determinism).

-- EDIT 1 --

I think I'm trying to do something impossible. I saw from https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html (section "Interpreter scripts"):

> Note that there is no way to get the argv[0] that was passed to the execve() call`

So I guess the best thing to do is, when the thing to wrap is a bash script, to directly append the "export" stuff at the beginning... Not very portable, but we can't get anything better.

I guess if one is willing to rely on a different GLIBC, it may be possible to modify `GLIBC` directly to automatically search for any specially-named file next to the binary/script in order to populate the environment variable... But it's quite a big change, maybe hard to maintain ^^ (and it would not make much sense outside the scope of Nix).

-- EDIT 2 --

For script, I finally found a simpler solution for my wrapper problem which works for scripts (binaries do not suffer from the same problem anyway, so I guess the old solution is good enough for them). See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I can't answer why that's not working as expected. However, you can provide a $0 to a bash script if you use the -c option, so `myscript` can be:

```sh
#/usr/bin/env bash
PATH=$(dirname "$0"):$PATH
exec bash -c ". myscript-wrapped" "$0" "$@"
```

The `.` (aka `source`) command finds the file to source from the PATH

Demo:

```sh
$ cat myscript-wrapped
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "my name is $0"
echo My args are:
printf "  %s\n" "$@"

$ ./myscript foo bar baz
my name is ./myscript
My args are:
  foo
  bar
  baz
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sadly, it's not portable to any script language, but if it's the best we can get... I'll wait a bit more to see if I can find a more universal way to proceed, but I don't think it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a not too bad solution for my problem: (I still need to consider scripts and binaries differently): instead of externalizing the script, I externalize the wrapper by defining a custom interpreter whose role is to first configure the environment variable (the language of this interpreter can be arbitrary, I just use bash), and then call the original interpreter (it could be any interpreter: bash, python...). This solution is interesting because it does not depend on the script used. It just has one drawback: the interpreter path must be absolute if you want to run it from a different folder.

`my_script.py`:

```py
#!./my_python_wrapper
# Must be absolute if you don't plan to run it from the script folder.

import sys
import os

print("Here is my name {}, the variable MYENV is {}".format(sys.argv[0], os.environ["MYENV"]))
```

`my_python_wrapper`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Setup environment variables...
export MYENV="WIN :-)"
# Call the original wrapper, and forward all arguments.
exec /usr/bin/env python3 "$@"
```

Demo:

```
$ ./my_script.py 
Here is my name ./my_script.py, the variable MYENV is WIN :-)
```

Comment: Nice idea to use env as invoker

Answer (score 1):

If you can detect that `myscript-wrapped` is a shell, then you have the `source` way.

Use a *shell-wrapper* named `myscript` like this one :

```
#!/bin/sh
. $*
```

`myscript` will be `myscript_shell` for the shell  :

```
exec -a "$0" myscript "myscript-wrapped" "$@"
```

Output :

```
$ exec -a myscript  ./myscript  "./myscript-wrapped"
my name is /somewhere/myscript
```

`myscript` will be `myscript` for the binaries  :

```
exec -a "$0" "myscript-wrapped" "$@"
```